# Как передать "тело сообщения" при запросе requests.get()

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests

Мне требуется передать в теле запроса некоторые данные на web-сервер, при этом, сервер принимает исключительно get-запросы, что указано в соответствующей документации. При помощи утилиты postman запрос проходит, однако в целях автоматизации обращений к серверу, хочу сделать запрос на python3 при помощи библиотеки requests.

Логика у меня такая:

```
url_callHistory = 'https://vpbx.ru/api/callHistory'
token = '**************'
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'X-AUTH-TOKEN': token,
    'cache-control': 'no-cache'
    }
body = {
    "abonentId": 23456543456,
    "callStatus": 'null',
    "calledNumber": 'null'
    }
body = json.dumps(body)
r_callHistory = requests.get(url_callHistory, body=body, headers=headers)
```

Однако функция get() модуля requests python3 не имеет параметра body. Можно ли как-то "нагрузить" запрос дополнительными данными в виде "тела" запроса?

> TypeError: request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'body'

Comment: У get-запросов в принципе не бывает никакого тела. Упомянутая вами документация, видимо, врёт.

Comment: «При помощи утилиты postman запрос проходит» — значит вы там всё-таки прописали что-то нужное, но точно не тело, потому что у get-запросов тела не бывает.

Comment: Попробуйте так: `requests.get(url_callHistory, data=body, headers=headers)`, но скорее всего нужно POST: `requests.post(url_callHistory, data=body, headers=headers)`

Comment: @andreymal, запустил я эхо-вебсервер на flask (https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/f7a36a8f9a1f93a647561977d3babdbdbd7b2a45/flask__webservers/simple_echo.py#L12) и отослал `get` с телом, и оно пришло, хех :)

Comment: @gil9red *«if the request method does not include defined semantics for an entity-body, then the message-body SHOULD be ignored when handling the request»* — ладно, с «не бывает» я перегнул) Но в дикой природе GET-запросов с телами я всё равно не встречал (кроме разве что этого вопроса, но я всё равно думаю, что автор что-то не договаривает)

Comment: @gil9red Думаю, людям было бы интереснее посмотреть, как Вы отправили `GET` с телом, т.к. вся дискуссия тут именно из-за этого :)

Comment: @МихаилМуругов, andreymal https://gist.github.com/gil9red/57df5e8f11aaa757862647468e8e624a

Comment: Вопрос терминологии, т.к. в postman есть таки окно, которое называется 'body' и его можно нагружать вне зависимости от того, POST это, или GET запрос. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tYKbIkdxA8kQqogrnzYcHFBzdN1OUWgZ/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'X-AUTH-TOKEN': token,
    'cache-control': 'no-cache'
    }
body = '''{"abonentId": 23456543456, "callStatus": 'null', "calledNumber": 'null'}'''

response = requests.request("GET", url_callHistory, headers=headers, data=body)
```

Передал "body" как строку, а не словарь, и все сработало

Answer (score 2):

Вместо

`r_callHistory = requests.get(url_callHistory, body=body, headers=headers)`

нужно использовать:

`r_callHistory = requests.get(url_callHistory, params=body, headers=headers)`

Но я должен пояснить, что в GET запросе не может быть "тела сообщения" могут быть только query-параметры. Это принципиальное отличие GET от POST запросов. Если все же нужно использовать POST запрос, то нужно использовать:

`r_callHistory = requests.post(url_callHistory, data=body, headers=headers)`

Comment: При передаче "body" в params выдает ошибку [500], возможно это особенность данного конкретного сервера. А при передаче всех параметров в data: r_callHistory = requests.get(url_callHistory, data=data) сервер выдает ошибку [403]

Answer (score 1):

GET запрос не имеет BODY. Все данные, которые необходимо передать в GET запросе нужно передавать как параметризированную часть URL.

[Здесь](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET) четко указано: Get Request has body - No